# System.UnexpectedException: Search Term exceeded max length: in apex class

Tags: apex, sosl

I am getting the below error:

> System.UnexpectedException: Search Term exceeded max length

Using this query:

```
String sosl = 'FIND {' + String.join(new List<String>(SAPs),' OR ') + '} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact (Id)';
```

my SAP contains 3125 SAP numbers. and it is trying to find the contact id of all

Answer (score 1):

The maximum length of a search string in SOSL is laid out in documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm

From that page:

> SOSL search query strings
> Maximum length of SearchQuery string
>
> If the SearchQuery string is
> longer than 10,000 characters, no result rows are returned. If
> SearchQuery is longer than 4,000 characters, any logical operators are
> removed. For example, the AND operator in a statement with a
> SearchQuery that’s 4,001 characters will default to the OR operator,
> which could return more results than expected.

With 3125 values you're trying to search on, plus the " OR " between each one, your search string will always be over the 10K limit. (" OR " is 4 characters, and it will appear 3124 times, = 12,496 characters before you include any actual data).

You will need to break this up into multiple queries.

Comment: how to add multiple queries in sosl.i have not wrked on it before

Comment: @VinothiniMurugesh The words you chose make me think you misunderstood my suggestion. I don't really think I can put it any more plainly though. Instead of a single SOSL query `[FIND <x> IN Y RETURNING Z...]`, you need at least 2, completely separate SOSL queries (i.e. `[FIND <x part 1> IN Y RETURNING Z...]` and then `[FIND <x part 2> IN Y RETURNING Z...]`) I encourage you to work on that yourself. It's a very basic concept, and  struggling with it yourself should be a good learning experience (making you a more self-reliant and knowledgeable programmer)